# MySQL WorkBench 8.0 on Windows 10 - Improve Import Speed

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0 on windows - is there any way we can speed up the import process? I am using the workbench import wizard.

It is now 6 hours running but at 8,091 records inserted. I have 5M rows to push.

Comment: the best you can do is running manually the script or run command to import the database backup...

Comment: ok will try using cmd

Comment: Thank you. 1M rows now just 17 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt using the command line client installed together with MySQL, and you probably would want to make sure you are using the unicode version to make sure internationalized characters do not get messed up.

Log into mysql from the client and issue the commands:

```
> use DB_NAME
> source FULL_PATH_TO_SQL
```

Comment: thanks this what i did LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/filename.csv' 
INTO TABLE preconsolidation
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;